# Stuck at Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djdk.net.URLClassPath.disableClassPathURLCheck=true -Xmx1024M -Xmx1024M when building spigot server

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, spigot

Basically I am trying to run a spigot server on my Raspberry Pi B+. However I keep getting stuck on this one line.

I tried to run

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xmx1024M -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.19.4
```

To build the server and this is the output:
[text](https://pastebin.com/gSbpQ6DT)

And it gets stuck on

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djdk.net.URLClassPath.disableClassPathURLCheck=true -Xmx1024M -Xmx1024M
```

I have also tried running

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.19.4
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you passing memory heap arguments? Omit xmx. `java -jar BuildTools.jar` should do it.